# Opencv/C++ - convert NV21 to RGB and generate Bitmap in android app

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm working on an app which gets NV21 buffer from onPreviewFrame() callback through JNI layer and then I convert it to RGB by using OpenCV in C++. Below is the sample code:

```
Mat yuv(height+height/2, width, CV_8UC1, inBuffer);
Mat rgb(height, width, CV_8UC3);
cvtColor(yuv, rgb, COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21);
```

Now in the android app, I get the rgb buffer back and try to display it by generating a bitmap from it:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
bitmap.createPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(imageBuffer));
```

However, it doesn't display a proper image. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Bitmap configuration change `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` to `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`

From the android developer docs,

> Bitmap.Config RGB_565
>
> Each pixel is stored on 2 bytes and only the RGB channels are encoded:
>   red is stored with 5 bits of precision (32 possible values),  green is
>   stored with 6 bits of precision (64 possible values) blue is stored
>   with 5 bits of precision.

Also, in your native function call keep a 4 channel Mat. Convert with `COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21`.

Comment: One follow up question. Is it possible to rotate NV21 image using Opencv? I generate Mat by using Mat yuv(height+height/2, width, CV_8UC1, inBuffer). However, when I rotate it, the resulting image is partially covered by some plain white color. The reason I'm trying to get RGB image above, since I ultimately need to rotate it since I was able to rotate RGB images nicely using opencv earlier.

Comment: You can rotate the YUV image, but it will produce great errors. As RGB values depend on the positions of YUV pixels. So now your image will have `rows=width` and `cols=1.5*height`. So the RGB image will have `rows = 0.66*width` and `cols=1.5*height`. If you want rotated output, you can either rotate the bitmap in Java, or rotate RGB Mat. If you're rotating RGB Mat, make sure that you create bitmap with appropriate values.

Comment: so I should rather convert NV21/YUV to RGBA_8888 as you mentioned in your reply and then rotate in order to avoid erroneous rotated image, right?

Comment: yeah. And make sure that you set height and width of bitmap appropriately.